# Meteorjs Fileupload Permission Error

Tags: filesystems, meteor

I'm working on a project using meteorjs and i'm using the cfs:filesystem package. Here is the code defining the collection.

```
Uploads = new FS.Collection('uploads', {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem('uploads', {path:'/meteor_uploads'})]
});
```

However i keep getting this error in my concole.

"Error: EACCES, permission denied '/meteor_uploads'"

Anyone have any ideas why this is happening? Do i have to change permissions on my project folder? If so how do i do that? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> "Error: EACCES, permission denied '/meteor_uploads'"

You should give the permission on your directory files with:

chmod 755 /folder -R